# Terminate LinqPad query programmatically

Tags: linqpad

Is there an easy way to terminate the running of a linqpad query based on some parameter?

For example

```
int x = someValueThatCouldBeNull;
if(x == null)
{
 //terminate the query
}
else
{
 x.Dump();
}
```

Comment: If this is the top-level of your script, you can just `return` to exit.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not.

Comment: Currently throwning an exception discards output, so unless you can write everything in some kind of file - this is not an option